# Convert onclick jquery to dropdown list

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm trying to convert this onclick event to convert to a drop down selection.  So for example, when someone selects "USA" from the dropdown list, it will do the same as the code listed below.  I have basically no programming skills, so the easier, the better if possible.

Thanks.

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery('.dataTables_filter INPUT').val('USA').trigger('keyup');return false;">A</a>
```

--- I tried this but can't get the dropdown value to populate the onchange event -----

```
<select id="countryList">
    <option value="">Pick a site</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById("countrylist").onchange = function() {
        jQuery('.dataTables_filter INPUT').val('****VALUE FROM THE DROP DOWN LIST*****').trigger('keyup');return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  Thank you.  I actually just found a post that answered my question.

For anyone looking for an answer, this is what I ended up using, although i am sure the format you listed works too.

```
 <select id="foo">
<option value="">Pick a site</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById("foo").onchange = function() {

        jQuery('.dataTables_filter INPUT').val(this.value).trigger('keyup');return false;
    }        

  </script>
```

Thanks for the fast response.

J